# Problema con 'required' y 'submit' en formulario Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo un problema el cual el required no funciona y luego tampoco funciona ir a la página hola.html

```js
 function confirmar(){
  
  var listasexo = document.formconf.elements["genero"];
  var sexo;
     for(var i = 0 ; i < listasexo.length; i++){
   if(listasexo[i].checked){
    sexo = listasexo[i].value;
   }
  }
   
  var hermanos =  document.getElementById("Idhermano").value;
   
  var dni = document.getElementById("Idtxtdni").value; 
  var nombre = document.getElementById("Idtxtname").value;
  var apellido = document.getElementById("Idtxtapellido").value;
  var direccion = document.getElementById("Idtxtdireccion").value;
  var edad = document.getElementById("Idtxtedad").value;
  var fecha = document.getElementById("Idtxtfecha").value;
  var mvl = document.getElementById("Idtxtmvl").value;
  
     var confi =  confirm("Enviando " + dni + "Con nombre: "+ nombre + " ,Apellidos: " +apellido + " ,con "+ hermanos + " ,Sexo: " + sexo +  " ,Dirección: " + direccion +  " ,edad: " +edad + " ,nacido: " + fecha +  " , teléfono: " + mvl);
  
  if(confi){
   alert("Se envía");
  }else{
   alert("No se envía");
  }

  var contador = 0;
  var txt='';
  
  while (contador != hermanos){
   contador++;
   txt += "<label for='hermano'>Hermano "  + contador + "Nombre: <input type='text' name='txtnombre"+contador+"' value='' required></label><br/>";
   txt += "<label for='hermano'>Hermano "  + contador + "Apellido: <input type='text' name='txtapellido"+contador+"' value='' required></label><br/>";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("nuevocontenido").innerHTML += txt;
  alert("final");
  return confi;  
 }

 function comprobar_dni(obj){
  var numero;
  var letr;
     var letra;
        var expresion_regular_dni;
 
        expresion_regular_dni = /^\d{8}[a-zA-Z]$/;
 
        if(expresion_regular_dni.test (obj.value) == true){
            numero = obj.value.substr(0,obj.value.length-1);
            letr = obj.value.substr(obj.value.length-1,1);
            numero = numero % 23;
            letra='TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET';
            letra=letra.substring(numero,numero+1);
            if (letra!=letr.toUpperCase()) {
                alert('Dni erroneo, la letra del NIF no se corresponde');
    obj.value="";
            }
        }else{
              alert('Dni erroneo, formato no válido');
     obj.value="";
              }
    }

  function comprobar_fecha(obj){
  alert("fecha");
  }

     function comprobar_telf(obj){
  if(obj.value.length != 9){
   alert("La longitud del teléfono no es correcta");
   obj.value="";
   }
  }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Formulario</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  
  <form name="formconf" action="hola.html" method="POST">
   <label for="nombre">DNI: <input type="text" name="txtdni" id="Idtxtdni" value=""  onblur="comprobar_dni(this)" required></label><br/>
   <label for="nombre">NOMBRE: <input type="text" name="txtname" id="Idtxtname" value="" required></label><br/>
   <label for="apellido">APELLIDO: <input type="text" name="txtapellido" id="Idtxtapellido" value="" required></label><br/>
   <label for="hermanos">Hermanos: <input type="number" name="txthermano" id="Idhermano" value="" required></label><br/>
   <fieldset>
    <legend> Sexo </legend>
     <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Hombre"  > <label for="genhom">Hombre</label>
     <input type="radio" name="genero" value="Mujer"  > <label for="genmuj">Mujer</label>
   </fieldset>
   <label for="direccion">DIRECCIÓN: <input type="text" name="txtdireccion" id="Idtxtdireccion" value="" required></label><br/>
   <label for="edad">EDAD: <input type="number" name="txtedad" id="Idtxtedad" value=""  required></label><br/>
   <label for="fecha_nac">FECHA NAC: <input type="text" name="txtfecha" id="Idtxtfecha" value=""  onblur="comprobar_fecha(this)" required></label><br/>
   <label for="telefono">TELEFONO: <input type="text" name="txtmvl" id="Idtxtmvl" value="" onblur="comprobar_telf(this)"  required></label><br/>
   <input type="button" value="Enviar" name="btnsend" onclick="confirmar();">
  </form>
  
  <div id="nuevocontenido">
  
  </div>
  
 </main>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no veo el boton  submit en tu formulario por eso no lo envia, busca como hacer un submit en javascript!

Comment: lo tengo como type="button"

Si pongo el submit, entra en un bucle infinito en comprobando el dni y nunca pongo el ratón ahí . intento darle a enviar con todo vacío para ver si actua el required y tampoco.

Comment: Si quitas el script funciona bien, tienes que hacer todas esas comprobaciones? y cual es un dni valido?

Comment: Es un ejercicio para aprender, tengo que tener la etiqueta <script> ...

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar el `input` de tipo `button` a tipo `submit` ya que si el formulario no se envía por medio de un `submit` nunca reconocerá los `required`

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="btnsend" onclick="confirmar();">
```

Luego debes colocar un `preventDefault()` en la función de `confirmar` así:

```
function confirmar(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    /*Resto de código*/
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Sí, por eso lo tengo el input como type="button" ... :( el type="button" dentro del formulario no envía ??? tiene que ser obligatorio el submit ?

Comment: Exacto, sin submit tu formulario no se envía, lo único que estás haciendo con un button es ejecutar la función a la que llama es por eso que dices que no te funciona el required, si tú quieres que se vean tus required es obligatorio el submit....ah y aclaro que en ninguna parte de mi código estoy usando jQuery, el preventDefault() es una función nativa de JavaScript

Comment: He puesto en el <body onload="cargar();"> en el javascript
function cargar(){
 
  document.getElementById("btnsend").addListener("click",stop,false);
  function stop (evento){
   evento.preventDefault();
  }
 
 }

y al botón : 
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnsend" name="btnsend" onclick="confirmar();">

Sigue sin ir lo de required y TAMPOCO me envía a la página hola.html
me saca el último alert("final")

Y si intentas enviar el formulario en blanco, se queda en bucle infinito en comprobar dni ...

Comment: Y todo eso no se resume en colocar el preventDefault() a la función confirmar ?

Comment: para cuando carge la página , se vaya al script cargar y le quite al submit su evento por defecto

Comment: Por favor dame un DNI correcto

Comment: Ya lo puse en el confirmar el " preventDefault() directamente y sí funciona " .
Lo de arriba era que me dijo mi profesor que lo hiciera y no va , jajajaja

Lo tuyo si va, gracias ! =)

Comment: Una cosilla, en la función le pasas "e" y haces e.preventDefault();

Yo no le paso nada y con preventDefault(); ya funciona, qué diferencia hay ?

Comment: Entonces era lo que te había dicho desde un principio ?  pensé que lo habías intentado antes y no te había funcionado....ahí si me corchaste con esa pregunta, yo tenía entendido que el `preventDefault()` funcionaba cuando se pasaba el parámetro `event` o `e` a la función, no sabía que funcionaba sin ese parámetro

Comment: Pero ... por ejemplo tengo el var respuesta = confirm(enviamos datos ?)

Recojo el sí o el no y se supone que si le da que no , no me manda a la otra página, pero con eso de prevent default, no me hace el confirm ....

:SSSS

Resumiendo " ahora va el required pero me lleva directamente al hola.html tiene que ir si el confirm es afirmativo ...

Comment: No se como funciona el formulario por que no tengo un dni válido, dame un dni

Comment: Pon el tuyo , lo hace bien.

Comment: el mío? que es un dni?  xd

Comment: Pon 43866570G

Es el documento nacional de Identificación Española.
http://generadordni.es/

Comment: Y para que el tlf no se quede en bucle infinito ??
Y para resubir el código como lo hago ???